# Session Variables are Null

Tags: php, forms, session

I've searched and tried over a dozen suggestions from similar issues on this site, but only a little closer to resoluton.

I am starting out with HTML & PHP so this is a very simplistic couple of scripts.

I am setting up an array with math questions (to test my 9 year old son).
The first script "mathtest.php" sets up the array and sets a couple of variables in the $_session global variable and then a form submits an answer to the question to "mathtest1.php".

My $_session variables are lost when I get to "mathtest1.php".

Please help.  I know I can do something with cookies, but I really want to advance in my understanding of sessions.

Here's the 2 scripts:

"mathtest.php":

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<title>Math Test</title>
<head>Math Test</head>
<body>
<?php
$arrayindex = 0;

for ($L = 1; $L <= 12; $L++) {
    for ($R = 12; $R >= 1; $R--) {
        $setupquestions[$arrayindex] = $L.'*'.$R;
        $arrayindex++;
    }
}

$_session["questions"] = $setupquestions;
$_session["randomkey"] = array_rand($_session["questions"],1);

?>

<form action="mathtest1.php" method="post">
    What is <?php echo $_session["questions"][$_session["randomkey"]]." ?" ?>  
    <input type="text" name="answer">
    <input type="submit" name = "submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The script above works as expected, but the script below has null values for the session variables I"m trying to access and use.

"mathtest1.php":

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $result = eval("return $_session[questions]$_session[randomkey];");
    echo "result = ".$result."<br />";
    if ($answer == $result) {
        echo "Correct!!";
    }
    else {
        echo "WRONG!!";
    }
}

$_session["randomkey"] = array_rand($_session["questions"],1);

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   What is <?php echo $_session["questions"][$_session["randomkey"]]." ?" ?>  
    <input type="text" name="answer">
    <input type="submit" name = "submit">
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Other details:
OS X, Chrome Browser,  latest version of PHP
XAMPP installation & scripts are on the same laptop as XAMPP, not on an external server.
session cookies are ON
...Trans_ID is ON
I have read & write access to the session save path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SESSION` should be in uppercase.

Comment: Seriously?   .... it works! ... I guess I've learned that programming is very literal.  thanks very much.

Comment: @Loumont, since this answered your question, you should mark it with the check mark to the left of this answer.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I was looking for how to close this but that's not possible.  I'll check the check mark  :)

Answer (score 2):

try uppercase!
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

```
$_SESSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike [function names](http://es.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)...

```
function bar(){
}

function Bar(){
}
```

...

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Bar() (previously declared in C:\tmp\test.php:3) in C:\tmp\test.php on line 7
```

... [variable names](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) are case-sensitive in PHP:

```
$foo = 1;
$Foo = 2;
$FOO = 3;
var_dump($foo, $Foo, $FOO);
```

...

```
int(1)
int(2)
int(3)
```

This applies to [predefined variables](http://es.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) as well, including [$_SESSION](http://es.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).